# macOS High Sierra - flutter command not found

Tags: macos, flutter

On a macOS High Sierra, I have installed flutter via
git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git

I have add the folder to the path

[image: path]

Configured the system to run all the applications

[image: Allow app from everywhere]

But I still have the error
flutter command not found

If I try to run it from flutter windows and not from command line, it works fine.

```
utente-pc:bin itmdev$ ls
cache       dart.bat    flutter.bat
dart        flutter     internal
utente-pc:bin itmdev$ flutter
-bash: flutter: command not found
```

Comment: Can you run it using the full path? including the absolute path to the directory

Comment: Please use text (in code format where appropriate) instead of screenshots of text. It looks like you have a capitol U in the `PATH` where it should be lowercase (`/Usr` instead of `/usr`) -- this shouldn't matter, but are you sure the rest of the `PATH` entry is actually correct?

Answer (score 0):

To add entry to macOS PATH variable try this :-

- Open Terminal
- `sudo nano /etc/paths`
- Paste your flutter path(e.g. `/Users/user/Documents/Flutter/flutter/bin`)
- Save the file and restart the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by below steps:

1. Open terminal
2. Go to your flutter folder
3. Inside flutter folder run this command `pwd`
   This command will provide you a path. Copy that path
4. Now run this command `export PATH="$PATH:<YOUR COPIED PATH>/bin"`
5. Now run `flutter doctor`.